# DAO nullpointer exception in spring service

Tags: java, spring, service, dao

I am facing a problem with a DAO in a spring service, the DAO is not instantiated properly.
here is my DAO, DAOImp, Service and ServiceImp and beans.xml file

```
package com.dao;

import java.util.List;
import com.dto.ProductDTO;

public interface ProductDAO {
    public List<ProductDTO> getAllProducts();
}

package com.dao.implementations;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.dao.ProductDAO;
import com.dto.ProductDTO;

public class ProductDAOImp implements ProductDAO{
    @Override
    public List<ProductDTO> getAllProducts() {
        List<ProductDTO> liste = new ArrayList<ProductDTO>();

        liste.add(new ProductDTO(1,"pc", 100));
        liste.add(new ProductDTO(2,"disk", 11));
        return liste;
    }
}

package com.webservices;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


import com.dto.ProductDTO;

@Path("products")
public interface ProductWebService {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("all")
    public List<ProductDTO> getAllProducts();
}
```

web service implementation:

```
package com.webservices.implementations;

import java.util.List;

import com.dao.implementations.ProductDAOImp;
import com.dto.ProductDTO;
import com.webservices.ProductWebService;


public class ProductWebServiceImp implements ProductWebService {

    private ProductDAOImp productDAO;


    @Override
    public List<ProductDTO> getAllProducts() {  
        return productDAO.getAllProducts();
    }

    public ProductDAOImp getProductDAO() {
        return productDAO;
    }

    public void setProductDAO(ProductDAOImp productDAO) {
        this.productDAO = productDAO;
    }
}
```

beans.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                   
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"    
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"   
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xsi:schemaLocation=" 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
     http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
     http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
     http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
     http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
<jaxrs:server id="productWebService"
    serviceClass="com.webservices.implementations.ProductWebServiceImp"
    name="productWebService" address="/productServices" />




<bean id="productService"     
          class="com.webservices.implementations.ProductWebServiceImp">
    <property name="productDAO" ref="productDAO"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="productDAO" class="com.dao.implementations.ProductDAOImp"/>
    </beans>
```

the problem is that when the getAllProducts() method is invoked in the service the nullpointer exception is thrown (property dao is null)

is there anything wrong with my code?
Thanks for help

Comment: It seems you are missing Spring and JAX-RS integration.

Comment: I dont think so, because If I instantiate the DAO in the method getAllProducts of the spring service everything works fine

Comment: That doesn't seem to have anything to do with Spring or JAX-RS. The field is `null`, if you instantiate it it is no longer `null`. That's not the point. It looks to me like the `productService` bean you defined in your `beans.xml` is not the one that is throwing the NPE. JAX-RS is possibly creating its own instance of `ProductWebServiceImp`.

Comment: At first, I have  created the DAO Spring service and Web service, but I noticed that the web service is just calling the service witch in turn calls dao, so I decided to remove service and keep only web service and dao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi here is a solution that worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xsi:schemaLocation=" 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
     http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
     http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
     http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
     http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.webservices.implementations" />
<context:annotation-config />

<jaxrs:server id="productWebService" name="productWebService"
    address="/productServices">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="productService"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>

<bean id="productService" class="com.webservices.implementations.ProductWebServiceImp">
  <property name="productDAO" ref="productDAO"/>
</bean>

<bean id="productDAO" class="com.dao.implementations.ProductDAOImp" />
```

Thanks to all the participants

Best Regards

Answer (score -2):

you can try to add @Autowired annotation in ProductWebServiceImp on your Dao.

Comment: the same error, the suggestion is annotation-based and it is equal to what I have done in the beans.xml file

Comment: you tried to add Annotation: 
@Autowired
public void setProductDAO(ProductDAOImp productDAO) {
        this.productDAO = productDAO;
    }, In your xml you declared the bean, with annotation you say Spring to use it. The annotation must be on public setter.